# VBA Excel : Delete excel row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a an excel file which looks like this :

```
Collumn B         Collumn C

John               4000
John               4000
John               4000
John               3201
```

I want to delete identical rows : John 4000 but to keep the row John 3201.
I'm using

`Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes`

but this removes row John 3201 and two rows John 4000 and the result is John 4000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are providing a wrong Range argument. `Cells` in this case refers to the whole sheet starting in cell A1, so if your first real data column is in B (as per your example), you are indexing (empty) column A plus the name, so Excel is right to leave you with a sigle John.

Modify your range object to e.g.

```
Range("B1:C6").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
```

and try again.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but if i don't know the range ? For large amount of data ? (I gave an example only with that columns)

Comment: You can enter range as a variable. For example: `Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(1,1).End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates ...` this will set range as A1 to last row with data.

Comment: One possibility is to select the desired range and use the `Selection` range, if the top left is a constant, then @iDevlop 's advise is good, replacing "A1" with whatever is your top left cell. If you don't want to hardcode, give the top left (header) cell a name like "DBStart" and use `Range("DBStart").CurrentRegion...`

Answer (score 0):

Just to shake things up, I decided to do this manually as an alternative. This actually scans through the range, looks for duplicate rows and deletes them:

```
Dim vRange As Range
Dim vRow As Long
Dim vRowStart As Long
Dim vRowCount As Long
Dim vDict As Object
Dim vCol As Long
Dim vColStart As Long
Dim vColEnd As Long
Dim vLine As String

Set vRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
vRowCount = vRange.Rows.Count
Set vDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
vDict.CompareMode = TextCompare
vRowStart = 1
vColStart = 1
vColEnd = 2

vRow = vRowStart
Do While vRow <= vRowCount
    vLine = ""
    For vCol = vColStart To vColEnd
        vLine = vLine & Chr(0) & vRange(vRow, vCol).Value
    Next
    If vDict.Exists(vLine) Then
        vRange(vRow, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        vRow = vRow - 1
        vRowCount = vRowCount - 1
    Else
        vDict.Item(vLine) = True
    End If
    vRow = vRow + 1
Loop
```